# IIS Stopping/Starting Application Pool

Tags: iis, service, application-pools

My application pool seems to be in the **"stop-pending"** state and doesn't react on anything. Neither in the UI nor in the CLI.

Is there an option to force the application pool to stop or mock the stop-message without rebooting the service/server? There are other application pools which have to be running.

---

Windows Version: Windows Server 2012 R2

IIS Version: 8.0

Comment: Have you tried killing the worker process?

Comment: Is it the same as restarting IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Application Pool is (normally) associated with one worker process named **w3wp.exe**

If the application pool becomes unresponsive, you can kill it. It doesn't affect any of the other application pools or IIS over all.

All sites using that application pool will be affected, but they may be already.

The application pool may start up again automatically, but you should check that.

If you have multiple application pools, you will see multiple `w3wp.exe` so you need to kill the correct one.

On Server 2012+, open task manager and click on the `Details` tab. right click on the column headers `Select columns` and tick `Command line`.

Now look at the w3wp.exe processes and find the one that has your application pool name in its command line. Right click that process and `End Task`

I don't think in older versions of Windows you can see the command line.

You can use third party tools like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), the second one can try many ways to kill a process.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Thank you. PS: column "Command Line" does not exist, only "User Name" :)

Comment: It's always a good idea to mention the Windows version you are using, so people can recommend the tools available on that version.